# How to automate git commands

Tags: git, bash, macos

Is there a way I can write a script to automatically run git commands? For example, if I am in my terminal, is there a way I can run a command similar to:

`run git push` which will automatically run the commands for me:

`git add .`

`git commit -m 'wip'`

`git push origin`

etc.

Comment: I think this [github](https://github.com/jamiew/git-friendly) project is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, you can either write you a shell script that does the commands you want or you can make a git alias like `git config --global alias.p '!git add . && git commit -m "wip" && git push origin'` to be able to run `git p` later on.